# ListContourPlot3D won't plot

Tags: plotting

According to the MMA 9 help:

[image]

`ListContourPlot3D` accepts input as `{{x1,y1,z1,f1},..........}` and at position `{x1,y1,z1}` depending on the value of `f1` puts a color to indicate the value `f1`, at least this is my understanding.

Now:

```
 plot = Table[{RandomReal[10], RandomReal[10], RandomReal[10], RandomReal[10]}, {i, 1, 10}]

 ListContourPlot3D[plot]
```

returns an empty cube. I have a similar problem [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65418/ploting-transition-dipole-moments-in-a-3d-structure).

Comment: Works fine on version 10.0.1 on Win8.1 64bit. What version are you using?

Comment: On OSX 10.0.0 it works, provided there are enough points (like 100)... edit: as belisaurius just answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need more points to find contours:

```
plot = Table[{RandomReal[10], RandomReal[10], RandomReal[10], 
              RandomReal[10]}, {i, 1, 100}];

ListContourPlot3D[plot]
```

or better:

```
ListContourPlot3D[RandomReal[10, {100, 4}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Come on, smart AND fast!? So unfair!

Comment: Is there a reason why it won't plot for few number of points? In this form, I cannot achieve what I want. I want to put at each position a small sphere or ball which its color depends on how much big is `f1` value.

Comment: @yashar That's not the main use of `ListContourPlot3D[]`. You may use other Mma functions